# Rendering in Black and white

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm doing some basic renders in version 2.9 and they are appearing in black and white after render, but in the render view while editing, they look fine.

[image]

Comment: can you please provide a screenshot of your rendered image with header?

Comment: Hello and Welcome, please add more than just the Blend file, like Screenshots of your settings, shaders, lights, descriptions of your scene and so.. The more info you add, the better for the users to help you

Comment: You need to pack the PBR textures into the blend file if you want us to see how the scene actually looks.

Comment: While files, images, and external links may be helpful additions to questions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be searched for and indexed thus helping future users with similar issues find it.

Answer (score 0):

It works well on my computer. Maybe you messed something in the "Display Channels" menu ? It should be set to "Color and Alpha".

[image]

Comment: Nope, still black and white :(